Translating computer error terminology and the use of "Bug" (漏洞) and "Glitch" (故障) in Chinese?
I have noticed that in Chinese media, especially in terms of gaming, people use the word "BUG" a lot. This made me curious on its uses when translated into Chinese and if certain uses are proper.
Here are translation notes I made on computer errors based on findings. I am not specialized in this field so I am sorry if there are mistakes:

Error (Mistake / 错误)
A mistake made by a programmer during coding.
程序员在编码过程中所犯的错误。

Consequences of Error (错误的后果):

↳ Bug （程序错误）:

A type of 漏洞 / loophole：flaw found in system.

An issue found during testing that causes incorrect behavior. It is an vulnerability in the system.
In gaming, it can refer to minor glitches.
测试中发现的会导致程序错误的问题。它是系统中的漏洞。
它在游戏中可以指代小故障的意思。
↳ 缺陷 (Defect):
A divergence between actual and expected software behavior.
实际软件行为与预期软件行为之间的离差 (Deviation)。
↳ 故障 (Fault):
An unintended behavior caused by an error.
由错误引起的意外行为。

↳小故障 (Glitch)
A minor type of glitch, thus a "小"(small) fault.

↳ 异常 (Exception):
Unexpected behavior that occurs during software execution, disrupting the normal flow of the program and often requiring specific handling to avoid failure.
在软件执行过程中发生的意外行为，打断程序的正常流程，通常需要特定处理以避免失败。

Results in... (导致。。。)

程序中未处理的异常情况。
↳ Failure (失效):
Observable consequence when software fails to perform its intended function, leading to a difference from the expected result.
软件未能按预期功能运行的可观察后果，导致与预期结果的差异。



Usage OF "BUG" in Chinese context:
While I have read on forums stating that "出故障" typically describes the outcome of an issue rather than the issue itself; the information I have found above seems to indicate that both  Bug (漏洞) and 故障 (Fault) are forms of an error (错误).

2 categories of error (错误):  Bug (漏洞) and 故障 (Fault)

Here are what I have observed based on my experience in both Chinese and English social contexts:
English:
While writing this, I came to remember that my English speaking friends uses the word "glitch" when referring to errors in a game. This caused me to change the title of this post. For instance:
"The game is glitching!"
 (游戏出故障了！)

Chinese:
Based on my personal experience, before "BUG" became popular, I have seen people use the term "故障" in phrases such as:
"游戏出故障了。" 
 (The game is glitching.) 

This seems to fit the English context, where "glitch"/(小)故障 makes sense as it is a problem that occurs during playtime. Wouldn't this fit more than "bug" as refers to errors during testing?
Nowadays, I see people code switch using "bug". This can be part of convention (约定俗成). For instance:
游戏出bug了！
(There is a bug in the game!)

When asked what "bug" mean in Chinese, I sometimes get literal translations like "错误", as in 程序错误. This translation is broad in context.
While this makes sense as well, I am wondering if using glitch's translation "故障" can be a more concrete translation.

That said, when discussing a bug that occurs in a context like a computer game, using "出故障" still seems appropriate. In such cases, bugs are visible issues, and saying "出故障" (a glitch occurs) can still effectively conveys that something has gone wrong.
What are your thoughts?

程错 is a common one for glitches especially in video games.

glitch = bug = a minor malfunction in gaming (小故障).

漏洞 - hole or loophole. It is considered a flaw in the system.

I shall update based on what you said

Updates
Found a discussion of glitch vs bug on reddit. Although it released 3 years ago, I still think the high upvote answer is better in the English context than my 3rd answer.

A glitch is a sudden irregularity. A high speed ragdoll clips through a wall. A graphics card freaks out and displays a jumbled mess. That kind of thing.


Bugs are discrepancies between the intended behavior of software and what was actually implemented in code. A button opens the inventory when it is supposed to open the settings.


To partially answer your question,

The translation of bug. As always be open-minded, I think either one of 程序错误/程序漏洞/毛病 is a nice translation. My translation is 程序漏洞 in a software developer's view. According to the life cycle of a bug, a bug at developing stage is an error/错误 caused by some bad code, but at testing stage becomes more like a hole that leaks/漏洞 of the software without observed reasons. Note that the discussion is about an informal internet usage and it derives from a term, so the translation is difficult to clarify net users' habits and the original definition at the same time. See Chinese memes about bug link1, link2, link3
How the word comes up. People choose to say bug in Chinese media is basically cognitive inertia since the word comes from the term in computer programming, which is an English-dominated field. @Monokuma already posted it in the Wikipedia link. In addition to my knowledge, a bug usually describes an unexpected situation. And yes you can think of the code-switch usage as 约定俗成, or a metaphor, or internet slang/网络用语 to describe it less literary.
Replacing bug by glitch. I'd rather not as glitch is more formal and literal. Based on my understanding of their English definitions, a glitch/故障 happens on a machine which relates more to a hardware context, while a bug/程序漏洞 occurs in some software. On the other hand, a glitch is harmful to both the subject and the user, while there are also benign bugs for users (which are usually harmful to the software or the software manager). As for daily usage, I agree with @kyc. You can generally say （程序）出bug了/bug occurs (in the program), （我）卡bug了/(I) got stuck by a bug (the English translation may not follow the trend), or specify the type of bug like disconnected/掉线, lag/网络延迟, shifting/漂移, stuck/卡墙 (trying to translate the words of different situations).


To me, 故障 sounds too serious (and also a little physical) for a glitch in a game. I would definitely use 故障 if an ATM swallows my bank card. For games, I would use 故障 for their servers, like 数据中心的故障导致玩家存档将被回滚至一天前的状态. If it’s just a z-fighting or something, I don’t think it’s a 故障.
I can’t come up with a general term in Chinese better than bug (毛病 is the best that I can think of, but it’s too general). If you want to be specific, there are many choices, e.g., 报错, 穿模, 贴图错误, 瞬移, 掉线, 闪退, etc.

I agree that 故障 sounds a bit like something more fatal. Maybe 毛病 can be a good choice of adjective in verbal terms
